# Remove first few characters if it is contains in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to remove the first few characters from a string if it contains an array
Ex. strings

```
$str1 = "W. San Marcos Blvd";
$str2 = "E. Point Loma Blvd";
$str3 = "East Palomar St"
```

Ex. array

```
$array = array('S', 'S.', 'N', 'N.', 'E', 'E.', 'W', 'W.', 'South', 'North', 'East', 'West');
```

In the above situation need to remove W., E., and East from `$str1`, `$str2`, ans `$str3`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What do mean by `first few characters`? If a value of `$array` starts the variable, or a specific number of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this...

```
$str1 = "W. San Marcos Blvd";
$str2 = "E. Point Loma Blvd";
$str3 = "East Palomar St";

function remove ( $string ) {
    $array = array('S', 'S.', 'N', 'N.', 'E', 'E.', 'W', 'W.', 'South', 'North', 'East', 'West');
    foreach ($array as $remove) {
        $len = strlen($remove);
        if ( substr($string, 0, $len) === $remove ) {
            $string= substr($string, $len );
        }
    }
    return $string;
}

echo "{$str1}=".remove($str1);
```

Note the way it finds strings earlier in the $array, which may be shorter than later ones.  So in this case it returns `W. San Marcos Blvd=. San Marcos Blvd.`  matching the 'W' option, not the 'W.' option.  You could rearrange the array to have the longer items first.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $str1 = "W. San Marcos Blvd";

 $array = array('S', 'S.', 'N', 'N.', 'E', 'E.', 'W', 'W.', 'South', 'North', 'East', 'West');       

   $str=explode(" ", $str1);
   foreach($str as $key=>$s){
    if (in_array($s, $array)) {
        unset($str[$key]);
    }
   }
  $str1=implode(" ", $str);
```

Use $str2 or  $str3 instance of $str1 for other string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the clever/reliable way, using regex and `preg_replace()`.  Using the `^` anchor and the trailing space in the pattern ensures that only intended substrings are removed.  (if you find you have cases where the trailing space cannot be relied on, then word boundaries should be used (`\b`).

Method ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/678e13508e671a8ad0fd3a6bac296594fb5dd7a5)):

```
$input=["W. San Marcos Blvd","E. Point Loma Blvd","East Palomar St"];
$pattern='/^(?:E(?:\.|ast)?|W(?:\.|est)?|N(?:\.|orth)?|S(?:\.|outh)?) /';
var_export(preg_replace($pattern,'',$input));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'San Marcos Blvd',
  1 => 'Point Loma Blvd',
  2 => 'Palomar St',
)
```

Or more literally, how to process one string:

```
$input="W. San Marcos Blvd";
$pattern='/^(?:E(?:\.|ast)?|W(?:\.|est)?|N(?:\.|orth)?|S(?:\.|outh)?) /';
echo preg_replace($pattern,'',$input);
// output: San Marcos Blvd
```

The pattern condenses your array of cardinal points while maintaining accuracy.  I have ordered the alternatives from shortest direction word to longest direction word -- this optimizes for speed.  Here is the [pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/t8TVF2/2).